# Order by with specific rows first

Tags: python, django

I have a generic ListView in django 1.11 and I need to return the object ordered by alphabetical order, but changing the first 2 :

```
class LanguageListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  queryset = Language.objects.all().order_by("name")
  serializer_class = LanguageSerializer
```

with the following Language model :

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

And I'd like to return ENGLISH, FRENCH then every other languages in the database ordered by name.

Is there a way to achieve this with django ORM ?

Thank you,

Comment: Your question is not clear please add more information about your Language model ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use two querysets and combine them to obtain the result as:

```
q1 = Language.objects.filter(Q(name='ENGLISH'|name='FRENCH'))
```

and

```
q2 = Language.objects.filter(~Q(name='ENGLISH'|name='FRENCH')).order_by('name')
```

Then join the querysets as:

```
queryset = list(chain(q1, q2))
```

Import Q from `django.db.models` and chain from `itertools`

Comment: Possibly `q1.union(q2)` could work as well, although I could not verify it.

Comment: Just as a side note: using `itertools.chain` will always result in two seperate database queries.

Answer (score 1):

Since Django 1.8 you use [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case):

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, IntegerField

Language.objects.annotate(
    order=Case(
        When(name="ENGLISH", then=Value(1)),
        When(name="FRENCH", then=Value(2)),
        default=Value(3),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).order_by('order', 'name)
```

This will annotate a field called `order`, then sort the results first by the `order` field, then by the `name` field, where English/French will get a a lower `order` value, all following languages the same so that they are only sorted by name.